# Installing Ubuntu without access to USB

Tags: system-installation, boot-order

I am installing Ubuntu on an inherited desktop, but I can't change the boot order (because the bios admin password is lost. I tried removing the CMOS battery, but no joy). So I installed Ubuntu on an elderly and failing laptop, and inserted the hard drive into the desktop. It seems to be working fine, the only thing I have noticed is that the device name in settings is the name of the laptop.
Are there any downsides to this method? Or a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I move Ubuntu drives from computer to computer, internal to external and back again, all the time. The only problem is if clones with the same UUID's are inserted at the same time. GParted has an option to create new UUID's if wanted. proprietary drivers should not be added before moving the drives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ubuntu does kernel optimizations during install, so I will not comment if this is a good idea or not. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can explain this for us :)
Device name is arbitrary as far as I know.

First thing I would do is find out if the motherboard has bios reset jumper or some sort of switch. Some older boards had this I think.

If not see if your board has quick boot select. For my PC I think it is F12. This feature might not be locked with bios password.

Another sugestion for you to try is booting usb from grub, since you have an ubuntu drive already booting:
[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB#:~:text=initial%20Linux%20system.-,Booting%20via%20GRUB,key%20to%20enter%20command%20mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB#:%7E:text=initial%20Linux%20system.-,Booting%20via%20GRUB,key%20to%20enter%20command%20mode).

Comment: I've just noticed one disadvantage of this procedure. Removing the CMOS battery reset the system clock, so I get an error message on boot. The clock updates to the network time, but reverts after shut-down.

Comment: did you manage to get access to bios in the proces? if so you can set the clock there.

Comment: No, that is why I can't set the clock. But I would have thought the clock is updated when the compputer is in use.